# Kedro on Databricks: Cannot import SparkDataset

Tags: pyspark, databricks, kedro

Cannot import SparkDataset in Databricks using;

```
from kedro.extras.datasets.spark import SparkDataSet
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

have you done `pip install "kedro[spark.SparkDataSet]"` ?
A new kedro project needs dependencies installed for connectors before use.

Also dataset types are case sensitive , so make sure in your catalog it is `SparkDataSet` and not `Sparkdataset` etc.